# Change the breadcrumb parent url params at runtime

Tags: angularjs, ncybreadcrumb

I use ncybreadcrumb. I'm trying to set the parent URL param at the runtime.

```
.state('order', {
                parent: 'site',
                abstract: true,
                url: '/order',
                params: {customerId: null},
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: 'Create New Order',
                    parent: 'customer.overview({id: customerId })'                     
                },
                data: {
                    roles: []
                },
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/order.html',
                        controller: 'OrderCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
```

The problem that I'm having is the customerId is not defined at the initial phase of controller. I need to make a ajax request to get the customerId. After ajax promise gets resolved it won't register the new customerId for parent. Right now I'm using synchronous ajax request to bypass this behavior which degrades performance.